# l'Hôpital's Rule and Multivariable Limits

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I decided to post another message regarding this problem because I still didn't understand it at all:
Can someone give me an example of function $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ for which:
$\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \dfrac {f(r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta ) }{ g(r\cos\theta , r\sin \theta)} =\dfrac{0}{0}$, and $\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+} \dfrac {\frac{\mathrm df(r\cos \theta , r\sin \theta )}{\mathrm dr} }{ \frac{\mathrm dg(r\cos\theta , r\sin \theta )}{\mathrm dr} } = C $ for some constant $C$ , but the actual limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac {f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ does not exist at all?

All I need is an example of a case where l'Hôpital's rule for multivariable limits when appearing in polar coordinates is not helpful (the reason such an example must exist is because $\theta$ can also depend on $r$ , but when using l'Hôpital's rule wrt $r$, we consider $\theta$ to be a constant... ).

Hope someone will be able to help me this time.

Thanks in advance.

Just to clarify things-
This is not a homework question... Only something I thought about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic example of a function that is continuous along lines but discontinuous will do it, if you allow repeated L'Hôpital:
$$f(x,y)=x^2y \quad\text{and}\quad g(x,y)=x^4+y^2\,.$$
So, in polar coordinates, it looks like $\dfrac{r^3(...)}{r^2(...)}$ and approaches $0$ as $r\to 0$ (with $\theta\ne 0,\pi$).

Recall that if we let $y=cx$, then $$\frac{f(x,cx)}{g(x,cx)} = \frac{cx^3}{x^4+c^2x^2} =\frac{cx}{c^2+x^2}\to 0 \quad\text{as }x\to 0\,,$$
unless $c=0$, but that case is easily handled directly. On the other hand, if we let $y=x^2$, then
$$\frac{f(x,x^2)}{g(x,x^2)} = \frac{x^4}{x^4+x^4} = \frac12 \quad\text{for all }x\ne 0\,,$$

If you want a single application of L'Hôpital to do it, let's try
$$f(x,y) = x|y|^{1/2} \quad\text{and}\quad g(x,y)=x^2+|y|\,.$$

The same sort of analysis works here: Along $y=cx$, $\dfrac{f(x,cx)}{g(x,cx)} \to 0$, and along $y=x^2$, $\dfrac{f(x,x^2)}{g(x,x^2)}=\dfrac{|x|}{x} = \pm 1$.

I believe that if your limit $C\ne 0$ and $f(r,\theta)$ and $g(r,\theta)$ are actually differentiable functions, then your result works, because we'll have
$$f(r,\theta) = arh(\theta) + o(r) \quad\text{and}\quad g(r,\theta)=brk(\theta) + o(r)\,,$$
from which we'll have
$$\frac{f(r,\theta)}{g(r,\theta)} = \frac{a r h(\theta) + o(r)}{b r k(\theta) + o(r)} \to \frac{ah(\theta)}{bk(\theta)}\,;$$
if this is a constant $C$, we must have $h(\theta) = k(\theta)$, and it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still can't figure it out ...
Let's look at the second example you suggested. When moving to polar coordinates, and differentiate with respect to $\theta$ , we get the limit of $ \frac{1.5 \sqrt{r} cos(\theta) \sqrt{|sin \theta | } }{2rcos^2 \theta + |sin \theta| } $ , and this limit does not exist (we can take $ \theta =r $ and then the limit is $0/0$  ... 
Can you please re explain why did you say that this limit is a good example for my request? I'm not even sure that this limit does not exist... Can you please give some more details? Thanks !

Comment: No, you don't get to put $\theta$ in as a function of $r$ unless you intend to do so beforehand and use the chain rule. If you intend the limit to be $C$ no matter what *function* you put in for $\theta$, then this can only happen when $f$ and $g$ are independent of $\theta$ — at least to the leading order. If you allow the functional dependence, then you are effectively allowing us to approach on *all* curves to the origin, which is sufficient to guarantee a limit.

Comment: In case you're not familiar with these sorts of examples, I've added an edit above.

Comment: I understand everything you said, but still can't generlize this idea:let's look at the following example:
$\frac{2^{xy}-1}{|x|+|y|} $ and we want to calculate the limit at (0,0). Is it legitimate to move to polar coordinates and then use l'Hospital rule ? If it is valid, then why ? 

Hope you'll be able to help

Comment: Well, I guess now I'm confused. I'm basically saying that your L'Hôpital's rule method won't work to prove the limit unless, in fact, you basically *do* consider all possible paths given by varying $\theta$ as a function of $r$, which is, indeed cumbersome. But, obviously, if you have a universal bound $|f(x,y)|\le Ar^a$ and $|g(x,y)|\ge Br^b$, with $a>b$, then $\lim\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = 0$ will work. I honestly don't see L'Hôpital's rule as relevant here. For your example, $|2^{xy}-1|\le \frac12\ln 2 r^2 + o(r)$ and $|x|+|y|\ge r$, so the quotient is bounded by $Cr+o(1)$ and does $\to 0$.

Comment: This is way too long for comments. But if you try to use L'Hôpital's rule, $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}f(r,\theta)=(\ln 2)r2^{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}(\sin2\theta)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}g(r,\theta)=|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|$, so, thinking about bounds as above, you can see the limit is $0$ no matter how $\theta$ depends on $r$. But, yeah, you need to do that step. I'm not sure it's any easier.

Comment: Great , Thanks a lot !!