# Limit of two variables, proposed solution check: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Does this solution make sense,

The limit in question:

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

My solution is this:

Suppose, $$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta $$ therefore $$xy<\delta^2$$ So by the Squeeze Theorem the limit exists since $$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\frac{\delta^2}{\delta}=\delta$$

Is this sufficient?

Comment: If you want to use that approach to show that the limit is $0$, then you'll need to know that $|xy|<\delta^2,$ not that $xy<\delta^2$.

Comment: Be careful. If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, then it's certainly not the case that $\dfrac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\dfrac1{\delta}$. You need to be careful with your inequalities!!

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262874/show-that-g-is-continuous-at-0-0).

Comment: Let $y=kx$ for constant k that defines the direction of the limit. Then the limit becomes $$\frac{k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2}{x}=0 $$ Therefore the limit exists unless $k=\pm i$

Comment: If you are using $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, then this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339400/find-the-limit-if-it-happens-to-exist-or-prove-it-doesnt-exist/339675#339675), makes the problem falls apart.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the continuous curve $C_{\alpha}(t)=(t,\alpha t)\subset\mathbb R^2$. Obviously $\lim C_{\alpha}(t)=(0,0)$ when $t\to 0$ and $$\lim_{t\to 0} f(C_{\alpha}(t))=0$$  so the limit of $f$ is probably exists. Now note that if $$||(x,y)-(0,0)||<\delta$$ then we have equivalently $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$$ and so $$|x|<\delta,~~|y|<\delta$$ Therefore if $z=\text{max}\{|x|,|y|\}$ so $z<\delta$ and $$\big|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-0\big|=\frac{|x||y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{z^2+0}}=z<\delta$$

Comment: $+ 1 \land \ddot\smile$

Comment: if I use $\dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}= \le \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{2}$,is it OK also?

Comment: @chenbai: seems right. but mine is better ;-)

Comment: thanks. I learn your method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more direct solution.

We know $|x|,|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, then
$$\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\le\frac{\big(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\big)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta.$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really follow your solution well - it doesn't seem to make sense to me (edit: see Cameron Buie's comment). Why not use polar coordinates by making the substitution $x = r\cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ though?

Comment: You can use polar coordinates, provided you give an estimate that is universal independent of $\theta$. See my detailed response at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405884/lhopitals-rule-and-multivariable-limits/405947#405947.

Comment: +1 @AWertheim : I would definitly use polar coordinates: $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=r\cos\theta\sin\theta\rightarrow 0$ when $r\rightarrow 0$ as $\cos\theta\sin\theta$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Another direct approach is to note that the square of the reciprocal of your function is $\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}$.